# convert nginx rules to htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting, rules

Can someone help to convert these nginx rules to htaccess? I was looking for some kind of online converter but no luck... all the converters are htaccess-to-nginx (((

I have also found a few examples

```
        location ~*/member/(join|register|renew|upgrade) {
                rewrite ^/(.*)  https://www.SOME_DOMAIN1/$1     redirect;
        }
        location /events {
                rewrite ^/(.*)  https://www.SOME_DOMAIN1/$1     redirect;
        }
        location /university/view/ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /tools/CMS/index.php?q=$uri;
        }
        location ~ ^/workshops/city/ {
                try_files $uri /tools/IntensiveWorkshop/iw_city.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }
        location ~ ^/event-recaps/(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d) {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /tools/Event/index.php?q=$uri&type=recap;
        }
        location /blog {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /3dpart/wordpress/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        } 
        location / {
                index index.php index.html;
                root            /var/www/SOME_DOMAIN1;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?url=$uri&$args;
        }
```

---

The problem is that stackoverflow does not allow me to put all code I have there.. anywya here is my htaccess file... everything that is under RewriteRule ^member/ just ignored and does not work... (( by the way it is cPanel/WHM .. I doubt it makes sence.. Apache is version 2 . In regards to bellow rules I think mos of them can be simplified... Everything is goes through index.php here and the point is to make few subfolders in a PATH to be https only. Like for example everything under http://www.example.com/member/ should be rewriten to https://www.example.com/member/...

So if someone can help me to make the following condition... when if in URL /member/ pattern appears it will be redirected to https then this will probably solve my issue. It sounds like REquest URI is including index.php all the time and this prevents from proper work of some rules.. not sure.
For example instead redirect to /member/search/ I am getting redirect to /index.php?url=/member/search/

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

## protect .htaccess and everything that starts from a "." dot
<FilesMatch "^\.">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

## http://nonwww redirects to http://www and https://nonwww redirects to https://www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

## everything goes through index.php
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]

# here is where it starts to ignore everything
RewriteRule ^member/(join|register|renew|upgrade) https://www.DOMAIN%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteRule ^events/ https://www.DOMAIN%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteRule ^jobbank/post http://www.DOMAIN%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteRule ^jobbank/createaccount https://www.DOMAIN%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteRule ^techspeak/ http://www.DOMAIN/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteRule ^newyork-ny http://www.DOMAIN%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteRule ^longisland-ny http://www.DOMAIN%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteRule ^sanfrancisco-ca http://www.DOMAIN%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteRule ^losangeles-ca http://www.DOMAIN%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteRule ^ralegh-nc http://www.DOMAIN%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteRule ^portland-me http://www.DOMAIN%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteRule ^chicago-il http://www.DOMAIN%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog /3dpart/wordpress/index.php?q=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^university/view/ /tools/CMS/index.php?q=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^workshops/city/ /tools/IntensiveWorkshop/iw_city.php?q=%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^event-recaps/(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d) /tools/Event/index.php?q=%{REQUEST_URI}&type=recap [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^member/(join|register|renew|upgrade) https://www.SOME_DOMAIN1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteRUle ^events https://www.SOME_DOMAIN1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^university/view/ /tools/CMS/index.php?q=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^workshops/city/ /tools/IntensiveWorkshop/iw_city.php?q=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^event-recaps/(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d) /tools/Event/index.php?q=%{REQUEST_URI}&type=recap [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog /3dpart/wordpress/index.php?q=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

The document root and index you can set up in the apache config.